# Identify My Spider

Tags: species-identification, arachnology

[image]
I live in Littleton Colorado and caught this spider because I haven't seen it before. Any idea what it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a male *Dysdera crocata*, a.k.a, "Woodlouse Hunter". They can be a little aggressive and might try to bite you if handled but they're no more harmful than a common bee sting (even less so actually since they won't potentially cause an allergic reaction).

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thanks for identifying it for me.